# Merging maps in Freemarker

Tags: dictionary, freemarker, literals, built-in-types, built-in

I'm unable to find any documentation on how to merge two hash maps. This is what I am trying to acheive

<select
    <@render_attrs commonattrs.**merge**({"class":"select"}) /> > ....

<#macro render_attrs attrs> 
    <#list attrs?keys as key> 
        <#if attrs[key]!=""> 
        ${key}="${attrs[key]}" 
        </#if> 
    </#list>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
commonattrs + {"class": "select"}
```

It's documented here: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_hashop